# whats this code for power factor?I do not understand?

Tags: c, power-factor-correction

This code is for the calculation of power factor, but I'm unable to understand it. What do the symbols (?) and (:).

How do I replace the standard code.

```
Pow_fac = (Pow_app > 0 && Pow_eff > 0) ? ((int64_t)Pow_eff * 100 + Pow_eff / 2) / Pow_app : 0;
```

Comment: Standard C conditional expression, but horrible, awful way to write them...

Comment: A?B:C is the same as `if(A){return B;}else{return C;}`

Comment: google up - ternary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an *inline conditional* - basically an inline IF-THEN-ELSE statement:

```
Value = (test expression) ? (true value) : (false value);
```

For instance

```
Pow_fac = (Pow_app > 0 && Pow_eff > 0) ? ((int64_t)Pow_eff * 100 + Pow_eff / 2) / Pow_app : 0;
```

can be re-written as:

```
if (Pow_app > 0 && Pow_eff > 0) 
    Pow_fac = ((int64_t)Pow_eff * 100 + Pow_eff / 2) / Pow_app;
else
    Pow_fac = 0;
```

It's a very useful method for (as in this case) deciding what to assign to a variable, or to make a decision as to what value to pass to a function.